# Событие click и получение данных из data из подгруженного элемента

Tags: javascript

Как сделать чтобы событие срабатывало и получались данные?

У меня в системе подгружаются уведомления, при некоторых уведомлениях и клике на них должно открываться модальное окно с данными например задачи.

Скрипт который показывает модальное окно подключается к странице в момент ее загрузки и ждет событий click.

код который показывает окно:

```
// показать задачу
    $('.view-task').on('click', function () {

        var id_cabinet = $(this).data('id-cabinet'); 
        var id_task = $(this).data('id-task'); 

        $modal.modal('show');
        $modal.addClass('modal-task');
        $modal.find('.modal-body').empty().end();
...
});
```

Код подгружаемого уведомления с data параметрами

```
<div data-notification="37259" data-notification-vid="tasks" class="notification-line leads view-task" data-lead-id="68413" data-id-cabinet="950" data-id-task="4318">

    <div class="notification-lead-namb"><span class="ucrmicon">J</span> Задача по клиенту: #68413</div>
    <div class="notification-info-rem">замер</div>
    <div class="notification-date">Вчера в 13:00</div>


</div>
```

Код показа окна используется на многих страницах сайта, как мне минимальными дополнениями сделать чтобы работало открытие окна при клике по подгруженному элементу?

Answer (score 1):

Решил так:

```
$('body').on('click', '.view-task', function(){
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Элементарно - ловить клик по контейнеру/врапперу и, через [делегирование](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation), работать к сообщением.

```js
let template = `<div data-notification="%d5" data-notification-vid="tasks" class="notification-line leads view-task" data-lead-id="%d5" data-id-cabinet="%d3" data-id-task="%d4">

    <div class="notification-lead-namb"><span class="ucrmicon">J</span> Задача по клиенту: #%d5</div>
    <div class="notification-info-rem">замер</div>
    <div class="notification-date">Вчера в %d24:%d60</div>


</div>`, // Шаблон для показа уведмлений, рад разнообразия цифры меняются. Just for lulz
    wrapper = null;

function showModal(){
  // this - это элемент контейнера уведомления
  let m = new Modal(), // Создаём модальное окно, класс ниже
      c = `Ваша заявка по номером ${this.dataset.idTask} показана в модальном окне!`; // Контент
  
  m.show(c); // Показываем
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  document.querySelector('#showNotification').addEventListener('click', getNotification);
  
  // Ищем обёртку (wrapper) и вешаем слушатель клика на него
  wrapper = document.querySelector('#wrapperNotification');
  wrapper.addEventListener('click', e => {
    // Создание делегирования (подробнее по ссылке выше)
    // Если есть data-notification, вызываем обработчик
    let el  = e.target,
        box = el.closest('[data-notification]');
    
    if(!box || !wrapper.contains(box)) return;
    
    showModal.call(box);
  });
});








// Вспомогательные функции
function random(min, max){return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);}
function getNotification(){
  if(wrapper.children.length > 2)
    return;
  
  wrapper.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', template.replace(/%d(\d+)/g, (z, num) => {
    let hs = false;
    num = +num;
    
    if(num === 24)
      hs = random(0, 24);
    else if(num === 60)
      hs = random(0, 60);
    
    if(hs !== false)
      return hs.toString().length === 1 ? '0' + hs : hs;
    
    return random(+'1'.repeat(num), +'9'.repeat(num));
  }));
}
class Modal{
  constructor(){
    let t, c;
    
    this.wrapper    = (t = document.createElement('div')) && (t.id = 'wrapperModal') && t;
    this.content    = (c = document.createElement('div')) && (c.id = 'modalContent') && c;
    this.hasContent = false;
    
    t.addEventListener('click', this.hide.bind(this));
    
    document.body.appendChild(t);
    t.appendChild(c);
  }  
  
  show(data){
    if(this.wrapper !== null && !this.hasContent){
      this.wrapper.style.display = 'flex';
      
      if(data instanceof HTMLElement)
        this.content.apperdChild(data);
      else
        this.content.innerHTML = String(data).trim();

      this.hasContent = true;
    }
  }
  
  hide(){
    if(this.wrapper !== null)
      this.wrapper.style.display = 'none';
  }
  
  remove(){
    this.wrapper = null;
    this.content = null;
  }
}
```

```css
/* Просто для наглядности работы */

html, body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#wrapperNotification{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1%;
  right: 1%;
}
[data-notification]{
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 30%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(100,100,100,.3);
}
.notification-info-rem{
  padding-left: 6%;
}
.notification-date{
  font: 10pt Palantino Linotype;
  color: gray;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px;
  right: 2px;
}

#wrapperModal{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}

#modalContent{
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type='button' id='showNotification' value='Показать уведомление' />
<div id='wrapperNotification'></div>
```